# removing redundant lines of text from a series of imported files

Tags: import

I am looking to remove redundant items from a series of imported files. I am using a specific sentence numbering system which is also shown. The first photo shows the output of the code below, while the second photo shows what I would like (when a redundant item is contained within an imported file, it is removed, there will never be redundant items in one single imported file).

Redundant items are present:

[image]

Here you can see they are removed:

[image]

The main file code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\newcounter{depth}
\setcounter{depth}{1}
\newcounter{pi}
\newcounter{pii} [pi]  \renewcommand\thepii{\thepi.\arabic{pii}}

\def\psetdepth#1#2\relax{%
\ifx+#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{#2}%
\else\ifx-#1\relax\addtocounter{depth}{-#2}%
\else\setcounter{depth}{#1#2}\fi\fi}

\newcommand\sentence[2][+0]{%
    \par
    \psetdepth#1\relax\relax
    \vspace{\csname pspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
    \hspace{\csname phspace\roman{depth}\endcsname}%
    \hangindent=\csname pindent\roman{depth}\endcsname
    \hangafter=1
    \indent\refstepcounter{p\roman{depth}}\llap{\csname thep\roman{depth}\endcsname\ }%
    \indent
    {\csname pstyle\roman{depth}\endcsname#2\par}}

\newcommand\phspacei{2ex}
\newcommand\phspaceii{9ex}

\newcommand\pindenti{4.9ex}
\newcommand\pindentii{19.5ex}

\newcommand\pspacei{7pt}
\newcommand\pspaceii{7pt}

\begin{document}
\sentence[1]{This isn't imported.}
\sentence[+1]{This isn't imported.}
\ExecuteMetaData[Example2.tex]{tag}
\ExecuteMetaData[Example3.tex]{tag}
\end{document}
```

And the two imported files:

```
\begin{document}
%<*tag>
\sentence{A}
\sentence{B}
\sentence{C}
\sentence{D}
%</tag> 
\end{document}

\begin{document}
%<*tag>
\sentence{C}
\sentence{D}
\sentence{E}
\sentence{F}
%</tag> 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/), it is possible read the sentences of the external files as vectors, then filter it with the `unique()` function and print the result as items of a enumerate list (or some alternative LaTeX ornament). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
<<results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
data <-unique(c("A","B","A","C","D","C","E","F"))
cat(data, sep="\n\\item ")
@
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The output should be:

> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. C
> 4. D
> 5. E
> 6. F

Comment: Does this compile as is? It doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @Elijah knitr is a R library. You need install R and  knitr. Then, the easiest way to compile this example is install also  Rstudio (good as editor of R , LateX and markdown code), open this file with a `.Rnw` extension and push the button "Compile PDF".  In the back room this export the `.Rnw`  to  a `.tex` file where the part with R code is changed by their output, and then is compiled as a normal LaTeX file. (but is not the only way, you can do this in a terminal, in a R session or configuring some LaTeX editors).

Comment: @Elijah Oh, I forgot that in sharelatex.com  you can compile this online, without install anything.

Comment: I tried compiling it on ShareLatex and got the following: "1. ¡¡results=”asis”, echo=FALSE¿¿= data ¡-unique(c(”A”,”B”,”A”,”C”,”D”,”C”,”E”,”F”))cat(data, sep=”item ”) @" any ideas on why that is happening?

Comment: @Elijah I guess  that you are using a file qith   `.tex` extension  and then the R chunk is processed as LaTeX text.  It should be renamed to another  extension that identify that file as a Sweave/knitr file. Traditionally is used   `.Rnw`  or similar  extensions, but in case of ShareLaTeX  work  with extension  `.Rtex.` In short: rename your `namefile.tex` to `namefile.Rtex`.